# How do I prevent a template from being reloaded in a Rails 3.2 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a Rails 3.2 app there is a template that has two pull down menus that are populated by a database. With jQuery i refresh the template when a different selection is made from one of the pull down menus. Other than that, i would prefer not to reload the template so the database is not repeatedly hit unnecessarily. To be clear, the template should not be reloaded when another page is loaded. I thought that the following would do it, but it doesn't.

```
config.action_view.cache_template_loading = true
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/cache_digests

Comment: best http://railscasts.com/episodes/387-cache-digests?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this concept.

```
@all ||= User.all
```

If @all already has a value it will not query again from the DB.